# Xcode: Font in storyboard looks different than by code

Tags: xcode, fonts, storyboard

I have a storyboard with labels. The label's font is set to System 25.

I wanted to make the font size dynamic, and I set it by code now.
I set breakpoints, so I know that "25" is actually chosen in my code, but the font size still is smaller than when I set it in the storyboard designer.

Does anybody perhaps spot where I might have gone wrong or any caveats that I might have missed?

```
//set label font size
CGFloat nFontSize;
if (bIsIPad)
{
    nFontSize=25.0;
}
else if (bIsIPhone_3GS_4_4s_Or_iPodTouch_3_4)
{
    nFontSize=12.0;
}
else if (bIsIphone_5_Or_IPodTouch_5)
{
    nFontSize=25.0;
}
UIFont *nFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:nFontSize];

captionLabel0.font = nFont;
captionLabel1.font = nFont;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that "fontWithName:@"System"" is not the same as "[UIFont systemFontOfSize:nFontSize];"

The storyboard property page seems to reflect "systemFontOfSize" when it displays the font "System".

When I chose "systemFontOfSize", the results were the same as in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your label to outlet (storyboard).

And after that, you set the font size for this label.

Comment: That is what I did. The font size is still different.

Comment: Or perhaps I did not... I ctrl-clicked the label in the storyboard, then I chose "Referring outlets", and dragged a line to the storyboard. But it would only select me "View" or the name of the label. I chose the label. Then it read "Referring Outlets: My View Controller". But you could be right about not having it hooked up correctly, since even when I set font size to 50, the font size is not changed. Can you help more?